# cuda runtime error (48) : unrecognized error code

Tags: google-colaboratory

I can run mmdetection code on T4 GPU, but it doesn't work on K80 and P100 GPU.When I execute the test code(), I get the following error:

```
# This is the test code
from mmdet.apis import init_detector, inference_detector, show_result
config_file = 'configs/my_faster_rcnn_r50_fpn_1x.py'
checkpoint_file = './work_dirs/faster_rcnn_r50_fpn_1x/epoch_9.pth'
model = init_detector(config_file, checkpoint_file, device='cuda:0')
img = 'demo.jpg'
result = inference_detector(model, img)
show_result(img, result, model.CLASSES)
```

This is the error output:

```
# errpr log
/content/drive/My Drive/model_train/10_酒瓶检测/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/roi_align/roi_align.py in forward(ctx, features, rois, out_size, spatial_scale, sample_num)
     25             # print('进入')
     26             roi_align_cuda.forward(features, rois, out_h, out_w, spatial_scale,
---> 27                                    sample_num, output)
     28         else:
     29             print('出错')

RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (48) : unrecognized error code at mmdet/ops/roi_align/src/roi_align_kernel.cu:140
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? Can you help me solve it?

Comment: I am facing same error, Did you find any solution to the problem???

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and on analyzing the issue it seems this error is due to incompatibility of Pytorch with CUDA version.

So the code worked for me.

You can refer the below link for versions:

https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/